# Copying an object from one Amazon S3 bucket to another using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy a folder from one S3 bucket to another using PHP but it is causing me problems. I can create the folder I want but I cannot copy from one folder to another. Here is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$key = '123';
$secret = '123';

$bucket = 'bck-users';
$keyname = $username;

try {
            //Create bucket for user
            $s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
            'region' => 'eu-west-1',
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'credentials' => array(
              'key' => $key,
              'secret' => $secret,
                )
            ));

            $result = $s3->putObject(array(
              'Bucket' => $bucket,
              'Key'    => $keyname,
            ));

            echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";

        }
        catch (Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }

        //Copy default files to bucket
        $sourceBucket = 'bck-users';
        $sourceKeyname = 'default';
        $targetBucket = $username;
        $targetKeyname = 'default';             

        // Instantiate the client.
        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'region' => 'eu-west-1',
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'credentials' => array(
              'key' => $key,
              'secret' => $secret,);

        // Perform a batch of CopyObject operations.
        $batch = array();
        $batch[] = $s3->getCommand('CopyObject', array(
                'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
                'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
                'CopySource' => $sourceBucket/$sourceKeyname,
            ));
        }
        try {
            $successful = $s3->execute($batch);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Is this a syntax error? $sourceBucket} why is "}" there? At copysource

Comment: Fixed it...copy paste error

Comment: Is the issue fixed now? Or still getting error can you paste the error too?

Comment: I'm still getting a failure message

Comment: What is the failure message?

Comment: I'm using a routing library so I don't have direct access to the front end / only the backend. I'm getting a code 500 server error....just with the copy part

Comment: A 500 error is something exposed to your _frontend_, by the way. It is a generic HTTP status code that indicates the server failed for reasons that the client has no control over. You need to dig through your web server and PHP error logs to find the specific error that led up to it. Otherwise, we have virtually nothing to go on here but guess work.

Comment: Going through them now

Comment: Also, the code provided in your question contains syntax errors. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center for future reference.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything in the access logs. Running the code from a test page creates an object and then dies with no error message. I'll have to wait for the front end developer to get his logs in the morning. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
  'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
  'version' => 'latest',
  'credentials' => [
    'key' => Yii::$app->params['key'],
    'secret' => Yii::$app->params['secret'],
  ]
]);

$result = $s3Client->copyObject([
  'Bucket' => Yii::$app->params['bucket'],
  'CopySource' => 'sourcebucketname/objectkey',
  'Key' => 'tragetbucketname/tragetkey',
]);

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to everyone who comes here.

I suggest a `copy` method that can copy to another bucket.

```
public function CopyFile(string $key, $to)
{
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => self::AWS_REGION,
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => self::AWS_KEY,
                    'secret' => self::AWS_SECRET
                ]
            ]);
    $s3Client->copy(self::BUCKET_NAME, $key, self::BUCKET_NAME, $to);
}
```